# Improving efficiency of a self join in postgresql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am performing the following query with a self join:

```
with t as (
      SELECT *, TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + tstamp * INTERVAL '1 second' as tstamp2
      FROM
      mytable 
      WHERE id = 'a'
      LIMIT 1000
    )
select v1.id as id, date_trunc('hour', v1.tstamp2) as hour, v1.value as start, v2.value as stop 
from 
    t v1 join 
    t v2 
        on v1.id = v2.id and
        date_trunc('hour', v1.tstamp2) = date_trunc('hour', v2.tstamp2) and
        v1.tstamp2 < v2.tstamp2 
where 1=1
limit 100;
```

The table looks like that:

```
id   tstamp    value    tstamp2
```

My goal is to output all the combination of "value" within the same hour for one id.
I have 100.000 unique ids and millions of rows.
This is extremely slow and inefficient.
Is there a way to break the query so the self join operates on time partitions (hour by hour for example) to improve speed of such query?

I have 100.000 unique ids and millions of rows.

EDIT: I found this which seems to be what I want to do but no idea how to implement that:

> If you know more than you've let on about the properties of the
>   intervals, you might be able to improve things.  For instance if the
>   intervals fall into nonoverlapping buckets then you could add a
>   constraint that the buckets of the two sides are equal. Postgres is a
>   lot better with equality join constraints than it is with range
>   constraints, so it would be able to match up rows and only do the
>   O(N^2) work within each bucket.

Comment: First rule of efficiency: remove the CTE, replace it by a temp view or two identical subqueries. BTW:  `LIMIT 1000` without ORDER BY makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks, temp tables might be the best, 2 subqueries might overload memory, yes you are right for the limit, just that by luck when I previewed my data I could evaluate results like that without having the cost of the order by :) but just luck here

Comment: Temp tables are terrible. `2 subqueries might overload memory,` Huh?

Comment: @wildplasser do you think a stored procedure where I first store all my unique ids and have a for loop evaluate the valid pairs of values for each id would be better ? or for loops are inefficient by nature ?

Comment: temp view I meant, sry

Comment: Your intention isn't even clear. Please add the table definition  (including KEYs and indexes) to your question. And *why* are you storing timestamps as integers?

Comment: In general set operations are preferable over any procedural approach regarding performance. A loop is more likely to slow things down than the other way round.

Comment: Could you please update your question to explain _WHAT_ you are trying to do? Preferably, show some sample data in the tables and an example of the output you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answers the question as originally tagged -- "Postgres", not "Redshift".

Unfortunately, Postgres materializes CTEs, which then precludes the use of indexes.  You have no `ORDER BY` in the CTE, so arbitrary rows are being chosen.

One solution is a temporary table and indexes:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t as
      SELECT t.*,
             TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + tstamp * INTERVAL '1 second' as tstamp2,
             DATE_TRUNC('hour', 'epoch' + tstamp * INTERVAL '1 second') as tstamp2_hour
      FROM mytable t
      WHERE t.id = 'a'
      LIMIT 1000;

CREATE INDEX t_id_hour_tstamp2 ON t(id, tstamp2_hour, tstamp2);

select v1.id as id, v1.tstamp2_hour as hour, v1.value as start, v2.value as stop 
from t v1 join 
     t v2 
        on v1.id = v2.id and
           v1.tstamp2_hour = v2.tstamp2_hour and
           v1.tstamp2 < v2.tstamp2 
limit 100;
```

Comment: A temp VIEW is better, because it allows the planner to use the indexes (if any).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately I am using Redshift, therefore there is no real indexing :/

Comment: Kill it with fire. Without indexes it is beyond repair.

Comment: how is your table sorted and distributed?